# Remove row in data frame if it meets a certain condition while also updating an associated total value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following info:

| Individual | Item | X | Y | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 10 | 10 | 50 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | C | 30 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | C | 25 | 25 | 100 |
| 3 | E | 10 | 10 | 25 |
| 4 | C | 10 | 25 | 50 |
| 4 | F | 5 | 25 | 50 |

X = the weight (in grams) of an Item.
Y = the weight (in grams) of an empty jar.
Total = sum(X) of all Items found in a jar + the weight of the empty jar(Y). Note the total doesn't always equal this in my real dataset due to material loss during processing.

What I need to do is remove rows with unwanted items (let's say items B, E, and F). However, when these rows are removed, I would like the value of X from the removed rows to be subtracted from the Total column in the remaining rows associated with the Individual. And yes, it is possible for an Individual to be completely removed from the data set as is the case for Individual 3. So, the data would look like:

| Individual | Item | X | Y | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 10 | 40 |
| 1 | A | 5 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | A | 10 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | C | 30 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | C | 25 | 25 | 100 |
| 4 | C | 10 | 25 | 45 |

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I do not get the calculation of Total.. Why is Total 50 on row 1?

Comment: It might be best if I explain what I'm doing. I'm working on data from a fish gut study. Individual refers to a specimen, item is a prey item (e.g., crab, fish, clam, etc) found in the stomach of the specimen, x is the weight of the prey item, y is the weight of the specimen's stomach when it is empty, and total is the weight of the specimen's stomach with all prey items still inside (so sum(x) + y). During processing, however, it's inevitable that some goop and whatnot is lost, which is why the value in the Total column does not always equal sum(x) + y. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution

```
DT <- fread("Individual     Item    X   Y   Total
1   A   10  10  50
1   A   5   10  50
1   B   10  10  50
2   A   10  25  100
2   C   30  25  100
2   C   25  25  100
3   E   10  10  25
4   C   10  25  50
4   F   5   25  50")


byebye.Item       <- c("B", "E", "F")
byebye.Individual <- 3
#how much should be removed by individual?
remove.from.total <- DT[ Item %in% byebye.Item, .(sum(X)), by = .(Individual)]
#calculate new fotals on filtered set
DT[ !Item %in% byebye.Item | !Individual %in% byebye.Individual, ][remove.from.total, 
                                           Total := Total - i.V1, on = .(Individual) ][]

#    Individual Item  X  Y Total
# 1:          1    A 10 10    40
# 2:          1    A  5 10    40
# 3:          2    A 10 25   100
# 4:          2    C 30 25   100
# 5:          2    C 25 25   100
# 6:          3    E 10 10    15
# 7:          4    C 10 25    45
```

Comment: Thanks Wimpel. For whatever reason, this isn't working for me. It's giving me an error at the remove.from.total step. It says the "by" argument is unused. I haven't dabbled in data.table much, so it's possible I messed something up when renaming things to align with my code.

Comment: make your data a data.table using `setDT( mydata )`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` alternative. Put the id's of unwanted items into a vector. Then, after grouping by `Individual`, calculate what the material loss is. Then remove the unwanted items. Finally, recalculate the total.

```
library(dplyr)

Unwanted <- c("B", "E", "F")

df %>%
  group_by(Individual) %>%
  mutate(Extra = Total - Y - sum(X)) %>%
  filter(!Item %in% Unwanted) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(X) + Y + Extra)
```

**Output**

```
  Individual Item      X     Y Total Extra
       <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1          1 A        10    10    40    15
2          1 A         5    10    40    15
3          2 A        10    25   100    10
4          2 C        30    25   100    10
5          2 C        25    25   100    10
6          4 C        10    25    45    10
```

Comment: Perfection! Thanks Ben!